# Android Html parsing from recycleview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, jsoup, html-parsing

Hi i am trying to create a news application.Already i fetch data from rss feed and diplay it on recycleview gridlayout.My requirment is when i click on tile text on gridview,It should direct to a detail page and there i need to display details news about that link.Already i am getting link,title,description from rss feed.But i am not sure how can i view it on detaial page.Pls support. I tried jsoup library.But when i try to add library in gradle i am getting compilation error.So am not able to work. implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.9.1'[image]

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of errors, copy-paste instead.

Comment: so what you have to achieve ? You want to integrate this library or you want show that details data !

Comment: i want to integrate this library and need to parse html data.

Comment: How did you fetch data from rss? Did you use webview?

Comment: No.i used rss parser